# How to prove that this set is closed in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

We have $T: X \to Y$ be a linear operator with $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces.

Now How to prove this set is closed given by $\big\{(T(x), x): x \in X\big\} \cap \big\{(Y\times N(T)^{\bot})\big\}$.

Can we also write the given set as $\big\{R(T),N(T)^{\bot})\big\}$ where $R(T)$ is range and $N(T)$ is null space of $T$.

Comment: The pairs $(T(x),x)$ belong to the space $Y\times X$, not $Y$.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by the intersection. Shouldn't it be $\big\{(T(x), x): x \in X\big\} \cap (Y\times N(T)^{\bot})$?

Comment: yes you are right, i make change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $T$ is continuous, or at least is closed, then the graph of $T = \{(T(x),(x)):x \in X\}$ is closed in the product topology. Also $Y$ is closed in $Y$. Orthogonal complements are closed, as the inner product is continuous. Thus $Y \times N(T)^\perp$ is closed in the product. The claim follows, as intersections of closed sets are closed.

Then we notice, that $R(T) = \{y \in Y\mid y = T(x) \text{ for some }x \in X\}$. Hence, you can also write the set as $\{(y,x)\in Y\times X \mid y = T(x) \text{ and } x \in N(T)^\perp$.